# ireport plug-in for netbeans doesn't export PDF or XLS?

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, ireport, netbeans-7

I am using netbeans7.3. with ireports4.7.1 plug-in

my program connects to a database and retrieves only one record that should be shown in the report generated.

and here is the code to generate it:

```
     try 
   {



        Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(host, uname, pword);

        File f1 = new File("report1Spring.jrxml");
        String path = f1.getAbsolutePath();
        JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load(path);

         String sql = "select Arabic , English, Nit, cnumber, (select mail from EMails where id ="+ Vars.pronum
         +") as email from allInfo inner join allAccounts on allInfo.id=allAccounts.id where allInfo.id ="+Vars.pronum;

         JRDesignQuery newQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
         newQuery.setText(sql);
         jd.setQuery(newQuery);

         JasperReport jasRep = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);

         JasperPrint jasPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasRep, null , con);

         JasperViewer.viewReport(jasPrint,false);
   }
         catch (SQLException | JRException e)
         {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
         }
```

the problem here is that:

I clean and build the project,

then execute it from the jar file generated, putting the jasper andjrxml file in the same dist directory.

then when I press the "Generate report" button, the report gets generated perfectly,

the thing is when I need to save it only the pdf,rtf, xls(single sheet or multiple sheets) gives problem. other extensions goes fine.
the "save as pdf" option generates a pdf file of size 0, and when I try to open it, it gives me the error:"could not open because it's either damaged or not supported file type",
and the "save as xls", doesn't generate any files at all.

and "save as csv" generates a files but when I open it, it shows symbolic characters that doesn't have any meanings.

I can't find the problem, and your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: any help please, I have a very tight deadline and I need an answer to my question please so I can move on this step :).